# Suppressing DCOM error 10009

Tags: dcom

I have a server which generates hundreds of DCOM errors (10009) every day.

> DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer
>   *ServerName.Domain*.local using any of the configured protocols.

This server does exist but is on a separate subnet so lack of access to this is acutally a requirement and so am not interested in configuring the firewall to allow access.

Many threads I've found in regards to this error say it's all down to the firewall or stale DNS records but none of them offer any advice in finding what's generating these and how to simply stop/suppress them. I'm not aware of any need to poll the server from this server so not sure why it's doing it in the first place.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from APGC DSI Team at the bottom of this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2010/03/15/how-to-troubleshoot-dcom-10009-error-logged-in-system-event/ I used Process Monitor to find the culprit. Simply ran it for a couple of minutes and then searched for the server name. The first result was a "NAME NOT FOUND" and this process name ended up being the culprit. I could then see from the application's interface that this server was marked as unreachable and the cause for this high level of logging.

For those interested, it was an SQL Monitor application by Red Gate which was causing this.